# How to embed IBM Watson Assistant chatbot into another HTML page

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have created my chatbot with IBM Watson Assistant from the GUI using Intents, Entities and Dialog and also tested the same using the "Test Yourself" utility. Now I want to embed this Chatbot on another HTML page. How do I do this? How would I start?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [section on integrations for IBM Watson Assistant](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/assistant/deploy-integration-add.html#deploy-integration-add). In addition the GitHub organisation [Watson Developer Cloud](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/) provides the SDKs and has samples. One of them is [Watson Simple](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-simple) which is a good starting point.